# Graphical modeler in QGIS. I can't find a model

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-modeler

I'm a doing a tutorial for QGIS and at one point I have to use *'Join attributes by location'* model but I do not find it in the Graphical modeler.

Does it have to be there?

I have to download it from somewhere?

I am using QGIS 2.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search for the algoritm? It's present in my QGIS 2.8.1

[image]